# Getting started with dump file analysis

Tags: crash-dumps, sysinternals

I am working with a legacy VB6/COM application which sometimes causes Windows 7 to crash. I have now generated a .dmp file of one of these crashes using the ProcDump tool from Sysinternals. However, I have never worked with dump files before. Which resources would you recommend for getting started with dump file analysis?

Answer (score 4):

Some more links that might be usefull

WinDBG and tools:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/

.Net extension for WinDBG:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/sos-dll-sos-debugging-extension

Comment: Perhaps the most important Windbg command to learn is `!analyze -v` -- it will perform some heuristics to work out where the actual source of the crash is likely to be (which isn't necessarily the stored call stack) and give you a very useful summary.

Comment: Edit queues are full, but the first URL in this post needs to be updated to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/ . It does redirect, but to a page that isn't the correct WinDBG download page. The URL I've pasted in here is the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

There are some books such as "[Advanced Windows Debugging](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321374460)" or the books on this guy's [blog](http://www.dumpanalysis.org/blog/)
that can help.

There is also knowing assembler that you will need.

Use WinDbg or any other debugger.  The above mentioned book is for WinDbg specifically though.