# Node Js Worker Process Dying Abruptly on Windows

Tags: node.js, windows

I am running a node js cluster on windows and I can see that the worker process are dying abruptly with a non standard error code.

```
worker 2136 died (3221225477). restarting...
worker 2172 died (3221226505). restarting...
```

These numbers are windows error codes.

```
3221225477 – 0xC0000005 Access Violation error
3221226505 – 0xc0000409 Exception Unknown
```

Are these errors logged in Windows Event Viewer or any other log where I can co-relate with node.js process deaths?

Any suggestions on how to debug this will be helpful.

Comment: It sounds like it may be a native code exception. Maybe this would help [Get stack trace of a crash on Windows without installing Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24208767/get-stack-trace-of-a-crash-on-windows-without-installing-visual-studio-c).

Answer (score 0):

The `Access Violation` error on Windows can be caused by for example having the binary addons compiled for a different system or different libraries.

You should either run `npm rebuild` or remove the `node_modules` directory and run a fresh `npm install` from scratch.

Also, take a look at those articles that explain the error in more details:

- https://www.reference.com/technology/fix-access-violation-address-error-32d89675057449d5
- http://www.tomsguide.com/faq/id-2119014/fix-access-violation-address-error.html